# Default value select option angular

Tags: angular

im new to Angular. And im having issues with selects and default options. I have an array of car brands that are being displayed with an `ngFor` in the option tag and i have "Seleccione una marca" which will be the default option. Here is the code.

```
<div class="form-group float-label-control" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': formStep2.submitted && !brand.valid }">
    <label for="brand" title="Este campo es obligatorio">Marca*</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="brand" id="brand" [(ngModel)]="stepTwo.brand" #brand="ngModel" (change)="getModels(stepTwo.brand)" required>
      <option value="">Seleccione una marca</option>
      <option *ngFor="let brand of brands" [ngValue]="brand">{{ brand.descripcion }}</option>
     </select>
   <div *ngIf="formStep2.submitted && !brand.valid" class="help-block text-danger">Campo requerido</div>
</div>
```

The issue is that by default the option is blank, and when clicked it contains "Seleccione una marca" and all the brand array. Is not making "Seleccione una marca " the default option. Thanks in advance for your time.

**EDIT**
I manage to solve it. By initializing the ngModel property with the value of the option i like to use as default. In this case i did something like this.

```
this.stepTwo.brand = "";
```

And whoala the problem was solved.

Comment: In Your componet initially assign 
stepTwo.brand = "Seleccione una marca"

Comment: Okey, and i should delete the option tag containing "Seleccione una marca"?

Comment: Yes you can delete that..

Comment: It did not fix the problem.

Comment: Add selected tag to your default option, and if you want to make it unselectable by user add tag disabled; Examle: <option value="Seleccione una marca" selected>Seleccione una marca</option>

Comment: I manage to solve it. Initializing stepTwo.brand = "". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to set default value for select:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption"></select>
```

And add in class:

```
export class AppComponent {
  selectedOption = 'Seleccione una marca';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using:

```
<select class="form-control" name="brand" id="brand" [(ngModel)]="stepTwo.brand" 
                    #brand="ngModel" (change)="getModels(stepTwo.brand)" required>          
   <option *ngFor="let brand of brands" value="{{brand.descripcion}}">{{ brand.descripcion }} 
   </option>
</select>
```

and initialize the ngModel with it's default value

```
this.stepTwo.brand = 'Seleccione una marca';
```